# Group by sorting by multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have tried building this on Sql Fiddle but I simply did not manage to run a simple SELECT * query on that.
I have the following query which is returning the user's profile photo, based on a multiple sorting of criteria.

1. is marked as main photo in an album
2. album position in nested tree (lft)
3. user defined sort position in album
4. user defined sort position in photos

I managed to do just that for a given user but I am having trouble querying the `users` table LEFT JOINING the below query in order to have an additional column that has the profile photo ID as value. 
It would have been easy if I wouldn't have to use that LIMIT 1.

/* the below query get the most important file for a given user */

```
SELECT f.*
     , c.lft
     , c.rgt
  FROM
     ( SELECT a.* 
            , b.catID
            , b.main
            , b.sort bsort
            , a.sort asort
         FROM foto a
         LEFT 
         JOIN foto_cats b 
           ON b.fotoID = a.id
        WHERE a.user = 79748
     ) f
  LEFT 
  JOIN cats c 
    ON f.catID = c.id
 WHERE f.delRequest = 0
 ORDER 
    BY main DESC
     , lft ASC
     , bsort ASC
     , asort ASC 
 LIMIT 1
```

/* database schema */

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cats` (
  `tree_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `system` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tree_id` (`tree_id`),
  KEY `lft` (`lft`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=119 ;



INSERT INTO `cats` (`tree_id`, `id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `name`, `system`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 232, 'Category name2', 0),
(1, 2, 2, 23, 'Category name 3', 0),
(1, 3, 3, 4, 'Category name 4', 1),
(1, 4, 5, 6, 'Actor', 1),
(1, 5, 7, 8, 'Modeling', 1),
(1, 6, 9, 10, 'Modeling Composites', 1),
(1, 7, 15, 16, 'Category name t', 1),
(1, 8, 13, 14, 'Business', 1),
(1, 10, 19, 20, 'Private', 1),
(1, 11, 21, 22, 'Personale', 1),
(1, 116, 11, 12, 'Hosting', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foto` (
  `id` bigint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `taken` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `time` date NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `delRequest` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `poza` (`file`),
  KEY `user` (`user`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=364411 ;



INSERT INTO `foto` (`id`, `file`, `user`, `taken`, `time`, `sort`, `delRequest`) VALUES
(357292, '79748_323722.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-01', 9, '79748'),
(357929, '79748_661469.jpeg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-20', 3, '0'),
(357933, '79748_699272.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-20', 8, '79748'),
(357934, '79748_239191.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-20', 6, '1'),
(357935, '79748_426873.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-20', 0, '0'),
(357936, '79748_513276.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-20', 10, '79748'),
(357937, '79748_183148.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-20', 7, '79748'),
(357939, '79748_237699.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-20', 1, '1'),
(357940, '79748_552583.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2016-12-20', 2, '0'),
(362415, '79748_299345.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2017-02-13', 5, '1'),
(362426, '79748_455975.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2017-02-13', 4, '1'),
(364127, '79748_158293.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2017-02-25', 0, '0'),
(364137, '79748_786692.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2017-02-25', 0, '0'),
(364138, '79748_136966.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2017-02-25', 0, '0'),
(364139, '79748_694159.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2017-02-25', 0, '0'),
(364140, '79748_279553.jpg', 79748, 0000, '2017-02-25', 0, '0');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foto_cats` (
  `id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fotoID` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `catID` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `userID` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `sort` bigint(3) NOT NULL,
  `main` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user` (`userID`),
  KEY `pozaID` (`fotoID`)
);



INSERT INTO `foto_cats` (`id`, `fotoID`, `catID`, `userID`, `sort`, `main`) VALUES
(252842, 357933, 3, 79748, 0, 0),
(252575, 357933, 116, 79748, 0, 0),
(252843, 357935, 3, 79748, 2, 0),
(252578, 357934, 3, 79748, 0, 0),
(252580, 357937, 3, 79748, 0, 0),
(252581, 357936, 3, 79748, 0, 0),
(252832, 357292, 8, 79748, 0, 0),
(252833, 357933, 8, 79748, 0, 0),
(252836, 357929, 8, 79748, 1, 0),
(252845, 357292, 7, 79748, 0, 0),
(252864, 357933, 10, 79748, 0, 0),
(252888, 357929, 10, 79748, 0, 0),
(252889, 357935, 10, 79748, 1, 0),
(252891, 357940, 10, 79748, 2, 0),
(252897, 357935, 8, 79748, 0, 0),
(252902, 357940, 3, 79748, 0, 0),
(253029, 357929, 3, 79748, 1, 0);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(79748, 'John Smith');
```

What I would like to do is query the users table in order to have a result like

```
+-------+---------------------+------------------+
|  id   |        name         |     filemane     |
+-------+---------------------+------------------+
| 79748 | John Smith          | 79748_552583.jpg |
|     3 | another user's name | that user's file |
+-------+---------------------+------------------+
```

I did not insert anymore users for obvious reasons.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6b98/2/0

Comment: Not clear for you discription, provide some sample data and your desired result.

Comment: I cannot see where any photos are marked as 'main' ?!?

Comment: That's because a user might not have any main picture selected in any of the albums. Then we will consider the next criteria, which the inclusion in any of the albums, sorted by lft.